# juju-gui how to enforce series=trusty

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I'm trying to use the openstack-base bundle on the charm store to deploy an Openstack cloud. However I'm seeing that nova-compute included in the bundle is the Xenial version. I want to use only the Trusty version. If I click on the charm and click configure, I see there's no explicit Xenial/Trusty selection available. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done via cloud:trusty-liberty (cloud:series-openstack_version) in the configuration settings for the charm in the Juju GUI.